# Send email to user when admin create new user in magento admin panel

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

Is there any way to send email to user when admin creates it in magento admin panel?
I have been looking at Magento's available events , but i dont think if they have any when a user is created.

Answer (score 0):

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_customer_prepare_save', array(
    'customer'  => $customer,
    'request'   => $this->getRequest()
));    


Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_customer_save_after', array(
    'customer'  => $customer,
    'request'   => $this->getRequest()
));
```

There are two event trigger when an admin is creates a User from admin panel as I mention above, you can create a observer and hook to those event and can able to send your custom email accordingly.